# Make any Wordpress theme Single Page

Tags: wordpress

I purchased a Wordpress theme on Themeforest. I thought it was Single Page ready, meaning I would have a scrollable webpage. How can I make this website a Single Page App?

Comment: This is going to get closed.  We don't have ANYthing to work with.  (And, FYI, your first mistake was buying themes from Themeforest.  You *should* contact *them* for support, but they don't offer very good support).

Comment: So WHAT would you need to know more then?

Comment: 1. The theme you bought.  2. The code for the page template that is a problem.  3. The desired result - should it list ALL pages? Only SOME pages? Which pages?  (Put another way - what do you mean by "single page ready", and "scrollable webpage"?

Comment: Thanks. The theme I purchased is http://healthandcare.ancorathemes.com/. The effect I would like can be seen at http://corsa.us-themes.com/. I'm referring to the scrollable effect when you click on menu items. I would like to have that scrollable effect on the theme I purchased. And this for all the menu items.

Comment: That pretty much means a rebuild of your whole theme. It's absolutely possible to make what you're after happend, but it will take some work. You should probably look into the possibility to switch it in for another theme, or look elsewhere for a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

I checked out the theme you provided, and it doesn't look like the one page scroll is a feature of the theme. There are couple things you can do:

1. Ask for a refund of the theme(difficult to do on Themeforest) and purchase a theme that includes that feature.
2. Contact the support team for the theme and see if they can help you. They typically respond within 24-48 hours.
3. Hire a developer that can integrate the one page scroll into the theme. This will be costly.

Comment: I came across this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-scroll-to-id/. Seems like this could do it, but not entirely sure